# Modify MUI component styles using themes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the colors of all MUI buttons using a custom theme.  Several tutorials and documentation imply that the following should work:

```
export const lightTheme = createTheme({
   palette: {
      ...
      components: {
         MuiButton: {
            root: {
               '& .MuiButton-root': {
                  background: 'orange',
                  color: 'blue',
               },
            },
         },
      },
   },
});
```

However, it doesn't have any effect on buttons.  This is MUI version 5.15.4, and emotion version 11.11.3.  Is there a different way to modify MUI components through themes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The library has excellent documentation on this topic: ["Theme style overrides"](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides), ["Button - Customization"](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#customization)

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          color: 'blue',
          backgroundColor: 'orange',          
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```